# Pass data to a redirected page using navCtrl.navigateRoot()

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic framework, I want to pass data to the redirected page, My code is currently using navigateRoot() to redirect to that page.

Current code :

```
this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(['/home']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this

```
this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('home',{ queryParams :{data:'Your Data'} })
```

and at the receiver side you need to define
activatedRoute in your constructor

```
constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: provide link from documentation

Comment: use this let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    queryParams: {
        currency: JSON.stringify(currency),
        refresh: refresh
    }
};
this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['page-slug'], true, navigationExtras);